# Code for Category, Tags, Archive URLs

Tags: categories

Working on an SEO plugin and stuck on something I thought would be simple.

Looking for code to generate just the URLs for categories, tags, search, and date archives when on that archive set. So if on category ABC there's the URL to www.domain.com/category/abc/

Was hoping it was something simple like this for the categories part:

```
echo get_category_link($cat->term_id);

or

echo get_category_link($category->term_id);
```

but apparently not.

The general code works if I add a specific category

```
echo get_category_link(123);
```

The plugin adds code to the head via wp_head()

The plugin (if I ever finish it) will be a replacement for so called SEO plugins that use noindex and nofollow to 'sculpt' PR/protect link benefit. Noindex wastes link benefit, nofollow deletes link benefit so they shouldn't be used.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a category archive, the code could be:

```
echo get_category_link(get_query_var('cat'));
```

in a tag archive, this could be:

```
if(is_tag()) echo get_term_link(get_query_var('tag'), 'post_tag');
```

the conditional was added to avoid an error messages if not in a tag archive.